# Why does the following assembly result with 0?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

I accidentally tried to call a virtual function of a class that was destructed. During the debugging with GDB I got to this assembly (AT&T syntax) and I need help understanding it. The outcome of the following is `$rax = 0`. Why?

```
mov    -0x188(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%rax
add    $0x58,%rax
mov    (%rax),%rax
callq  *%rax
```

I tried running the following in gdb:

```
p $rbp gives 0x7f70277a2680
p $rbp - 0x88 gives 0x7f70277a25f8
x 0x7f70277a25f8 gives 0x0185b4cb
p 0x0185b4cb + 0x58 gives 25539875
x 25539875 gives 0x8d481f76
```

If `p $rax` is 0 shouldn't `x 25539875` also give 0? What am I missing?

---

Edit:

As @prl said I accidentally reduced 0x88 instead of 0x188. After fixing all is well and `p $rax` results with 0. Thank you.

```
p $rbp gives 0x7f70277a2680
p $rbp - 0x188 gives 0x7f70277a24f8
x/a 0x7f70277a24f8 gives 0x7ffc52e591d0
p 0x7ffc52e591d0 + 0x58 gives 140721699263016
x/a 140721699263016 gives 0
```

Comment: Make sure you are printing 8 bytes. Better use `x/a` for pointers.

Comment: `callq *%rax` is an indirect function call.  Function calls modify the call-clobbered registers including RAX.  It can certainly leave RAX = 0 independently of RBP or stack data before the call.

Comment: I assumed gdb is stopped at the `call *%rax` due to the null pointer causing a segfault.

Comment: In your gdb trace, you printed rbp - 88 instead of rbp - 188.

Comment: @prl good catch :)

Comment: @prl you are correct. After reducing 0x188 instead of 0x88 it is solved. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Typo problems can just get closed as typo, no need for an answer because it's not going to be helpful to future readers.